# Setting Authorization header doesn't work in alamofire with ios9

Tags: ios9, alamofire

I had this bit of code that was setting the authorization header for all requests - and it worked in ios8 but stopped working in ios9.  No runtime or compile time errors - but it just doesn't seem to set this header when the request is sent.

I've upgraded to the latest AlamoFire 2.

```
 manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token]
```

UPDATE:

I just found this in the issue logs but not sure I understand the answer.  The sample code they give - it doesn't seem to be creating a new session in a different way- or is that supposed to be set like that before every request?

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/545

> Changing mutable values within the configuration object has no effect
>   on the current session, but you can create a new session with the
>   modified configuration object.

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
defaultHeaders["DNT"] = "1 (Do Not Track Enabled)"

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Using this information, I tried using a new manager with the my authorization token and that works - but I'd like to to just update the default headers in the AlamoFire manager directly so that I don't have to repeat for every request.